# Why is the same query returning different results on different R sessions using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, rstudio-server

While I was working on a project with a colleague of mine, that involved using the package dplyr from tidyverse to manipulate a data frame, I've noticed that some of our results ware different even though we ware using the same code and the same data.

Session infos from both R sessions:

**Desktop:**

```
> sessionInfo()

R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
 [1] forcats_0.4.0   stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_0.8.3    
 [4] purrr_0.3.3     readr_1.3.1     tidyr_1.0.0    
 [7] tibble_2.1.3    ggplot2_3.2.1   tidyverse_1.3.0
[10] sp_1.3-2
```

**RStudio Cloud**

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/liblapack.so.3.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C           LC_TIME=C.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=C.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=C.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=C.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C              LC_ADDRESS=C          
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C         LC_MEASUREMENT=C.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C   

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] randomNames_1.4-0.0  plotly_4.9.2.1       lubridate_1.7.9     
 [4] openintro_2.0.0      usdata_0.1.0         cherryblossom_0.1.0 
 [7] airports_0.1.0       leaflet_2.0.3        forcats_0.5.0       
[10] stringr_1.4.0        dplyr_1.0.0          purrr_0.3.4         
[13] readr_1.3.1          tidyr_1.1.0          tibble_3.0.2        
[16] ggplot2_3.3.2        tidyverse_1.3.0      shinydashboard_0.7.1
[19] shiny_1.5.0
```

**Reproducible example using Iris:**

```
library(tidyverse)

#lets say that each flower on the data frame iris had a name


iris$name <-c("Jackson","al-Jalali","Tamblyn","Beckham","Knipp","Chen","el-Hares","al-Shaheen","Boyd","Gurung","Demolli","el-Omer","Christensen","Ayele","Wilson","Arriaga","el-Vaziri","Aragon","Demoudt","Gray","Raiburn","al-Aziz","Phouthavong","John","Bortolutti","Ellis","Williams","Gonzalez","Valenzuela","Smith","el-Ishak","al-Tabet","Perez","Watson","el-Imam","Kerr","Morales-Gonzale","Bell","Haines","Gutierrez","SalcidoIbarra","Jimenez","al-Bari","Gosnell","Kocsis","Pratt","Tenorio","Merriweather","Damiana","al-Jafari","Edwards","Mujkic","Lam","Russell","Christy","el-Zahra","al-Lodi","Murry","Haro","Chu","Espinoza","Sahnd","Sands","el-Nagi","Dickerson","Carlton","Flood","Tran","Cruz","Yu","West","Franklin","Dupree","Delger","White","Olivero","Sem","al-Muhammed","Shafer","Senette","Hudson","Lattimer","Lyons","Grim","Grove","Truong","LynnGoin","el-Hassan","Cline","Adams","Watkins","Littlejohn","Gatzke","Vandyke","Yocum","Ng","Ortiz","Schwartz","Torres","Hernandez","Krien","Thyfault","al-Ansari","el-Shahin","el-Hashemi","Hereford","Navajo","Bickel","Saiganesh","Polson","Bates","Griffith","Krueger","Yang","AlAmin","Linthicum","Gallegos","Murphy","Johnson","Basurto","Rendon","el-Minhas","Khan","al-Ebrahim","Macgilvray","Farrell","Ricord","Lovato","Sanchez","Palmer","Turner","al-Fares","Ball","Ji","OrtizMorales","Fan","Isaac","Barger","Eddins","Fabrizio","Hedin","Brodsky","Leggett","Le","Guichard","al-Rahim","Benefiel","Sullivan","Milender","Smith")
  

#and that for some reason the same flower can appear more than once in the data frame
sample_index<-c(14,50,118,43,14,118,90,91,91,92,137,99,72,26,
7,137,78,81,43,103,117,76,143,32,109,7,137,74,
23,53,135,53,34,69,72,76,63,141,97,91,38,21,
41,90,60,16,116,94,6,86,86,39,118,50,34,4,
13,69,127,52,22,89,25,35,112,30,140,121,110,64,
142,67,122,79,85,136,51,74,106,98,74,127,17,46,
54,110,94,79,24,113,107,135,102,135,5,70,16,24,
32,21)

iris_big <- rbind(iris,iris[sample_index,])
```

I was trying to know how many unique flowers of each Specie there ware so I wrote the following query:

```
 
iris_big %>% 
  group_by(name,Species) %>% 
  count() %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  count(Species)
```

**The problem is**, it returns two different results, one on my desktop and another on my friend's desktop (he was using Rstudio Cloud).

**My desktop:**

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Species        n
  <fct>      <int>
1 setosa        50
2 versicolor    50
3 virginica     50
```

**Rstudio Cloud:**

```
Using `n` as weighting variable
ℹ Quiet this message with `wt = n` or count rows with `wt = 1`
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Species        n
  <fct>      <int>
1 setosa        83
2 versicolor    80
3 virginica     87
```

I eventually fixed this issue by using the following querie:

```
iris_big %>% 
  group_by(name,Species) %>% 
  count() %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  select(Species) %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  count()

# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   Species [3]
  Species        n
  <fct>      <int>
1 setosa        50
2 versicolor    50
3 virginica     50
```

But I would like to know why this is happening.

Comment: Did you try using just `iris_big %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  count()`?

Comment: did you verify same version of  `R` and of `RStudio` on all systems and all locations, and that you are using the same "pipe" package for your `%>%` operators?

Comment: Just tried your code,  using Rgui.exe , R 4.02 on a windows machine;  I get the same 80,83,... you got.  Note:  I  used `magrittr` and `dplyr` to support some of your function and operator calls.

Comment: What version of `dplyr` are you using (`packageVersion("dplyr")`)?

Comment: R-3.6 changed the pseudo-random number generator a little. This results in all random sequences being different when comparing R < 3.6 with R >= 3.6.0. Compare your R versions. (See https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-announce/2019/000641.html for "significant user-level changes". While it references the discrete uniform distribution, the effect is felt in many places.) (Further, as a soap-box, this suggests that all reproducible questions should reference the version of R as well; and while R-3.6 can revert to R-3.5 randomness, the reverse is not possible.)

Comment: @DominikS.Meier packageVersion("dplyr") - ‘0.8.3’

Comment: @DominikS.Meier on my desktop V. 0.8.3 and on RstudioCloud V. 1.0.0

Comment: @CarlWitthoft the R version on my desktop is R version 3.6.1

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for your advice but I don't think that any of the answers have helped me to clarify my question so far.
I've already edited my question removing some random parts of the reproducible example to make it simpler for the readers.

Comment: Okay. There is still information, then, that would be useful. Namely, what versions of R and `dplyr` are being used on both systems? Perhaps `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: @r2evans I've just updated my question with your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Up front, I'm submitting this as an alternate answer since my [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62942195/3358272) (about the change in `sample.int` between R-3.5 and R-3.6) still seems relevant to the question of *"Why is the same query returning different results on different R sessions"*; it is not what is causing **this** symptom, but it very easily could have been since the first version of your question used `sample`. Instead, the real culprit here is due to an equally "major" version change in dplyr.)

You are experiencing a significant change in the behavior of `dplyr::count`.

In dplyr-0.8.3, `?count` says:

```
      wt: (Optional) If omitted (and no variable named 'n' exists in
          the data), will count the number of rows. If specified, will
          perform a "weighted" tally by summing the (non-missing)
          values of variable 'wt'. A column named 'n' (but not 'nn' or
          'nnn') will be used as weighting variable by default in
          'tally()', but not in 'count()'. This argument is
          automatically quoted and later evaluated in the context of
          the data frame. It supports unquoting. See
          'vignette("programming")' for an introduction to these
          concepts.
```

In dplyr-1.0.0:

```
      wt: <'data-masking'> Frequency weights. Can be a variable (or
          combination of variables) or 'NULL'. 'wt' is computed once
          for each unique combination of the counted variables.

            • If a variable, 'count()' will compute 'sum(wt)' for each
              unique combination.

            • If 'NULL', the default, the computation depends on
              whether a column of frequency counts 'n' exists in the
              data frame. If it exists, the counts are computed with
              'sum(n)' for each unique combination. Otherwise, 'n()' is
              used to compute the counts. Supply 'wt = n()' to force
              this behaviour even if you have an 'n' column in the data
              frame.
```

The important part to see is that in 0.8.3, it says that a *"column named 'n' ... will be used ... in 'tally()' but not in 'count()'"*. However, in 1.0.0, it does not include that verbiage. I reproduced your results by using R-3.5.3/dplyr-0.8.3 and R-4.0.2/dplyr-1.0.0.

The way around it is one of two ways:

1. Use `count(..., wt=n())`:

   ```r
   R.version$version.string
   # [1] "R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)"
   iris_big %>%
     group_by(name,Species) %>%
     count() %>%
     ungroup() %>%
     count(Species, wt = n())
   # # A tibble: 3 x 2
   #   Species        n
   #   <fct>      <int>
   # 1 setosa        50
   # 2 versicolor    50
   # 3 virginica     50
   ```

   ```r
   R.version$version.string
   # [1] "R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)"
   iris_big %>%
     group_by(name,Species) %>%
     count() %>%
     ungroup() %>%
     count(Species, wt = n())
   # # A tibble: 3 x 2
   #   Species        n
   #   <fct>      <int>
   # 1 setosa        50
   # 2 versicolor    50
   # 3 virginica     50
   ```
2. Shift to using `tally` within grouping, as in

   ```r
   iris_big %>%
     group_by(name,Species) %>%
     count() %>%
     group_by(Species) %>%
     tally()
   ```

Or you can go with another option:

3. Realize that this is issue [dplyr#5298](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/5298), which is fixed in the yet-to-be-released dplyr-1.0.1 (I do not know a timeline). With that, the RStudio Cloud user can opt for the github version of dplyr to benefit from [dplyr#5349](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/pull/5349), a PR that has already been merged. This should revert `count`'s behavior back to the pre-1.0.0 behavior (despite [Hadley's opinion](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/5298#issuecomment-639561426) on the matter).

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I apologize for the mistake of using the function sample in such a question.

Comment: No worries, it's not always obvious what's relevant. Glad we brought it around to (what I believe is) the real culprit.

Comment: I just hope to be able to run my codes in the future without knowing what version of the packages I was using. Perhaps I should start documenting it. Again, thanks for your help @r2evans

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Tidyverse is really awesome, but it's very annoying these changes. Old codes stop working very fast and we are never sure if our today's code will resist when the future comes...

Comment: Something I find related and interesting, with respect to dependency and reproducible reporting: in an R package, the typical (in my experience) constraint on dep versions is to set the *minimum* version by including it in the `DESCRIPTION` file. It is possible to do the "range" thing (e.g., `Imports: pkgname (>= 1.0.0), pkgname (< 2.0.0)`) to restrict to a known major version (assuming semantic versioning), but I have not seen it. **Regardless**, since you (@Luis) might not be writing a package, there is always the `renv` package to ensure you always use a known-good collection of packages.

Comment: Thanks! I didn’t know about the renv package!! I’ll check it out

Comment: Quick follow-up: I just queried all available packages (on CRAN, over 16k for win10): `hutils` explicitly uses `<` pkg-ver restrictions on the assumption of semantic versioning. No packages used the "range" constraints I mentioned above. \*shrug\*

Answer (score 3):

You're using `sample`, which is using a discrete uniform distribution.

In R's [PR#17494](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17494) (and associated [mailing-list thread](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2018-September/076817.html)), a problem with non-uniform sampling was discussed and fixed. This went into effect in R-3.6.

This can be demonstrated simply:

- R-3.5.3-64bit (win10)

  ```r
  set.seed(123) ; sample(5)
  # [1] 2 4 5 3 1
  ```
- R-3.6.1-64bit (win10)

  ```r
  set.seed(123) ; sample(5)
  # [1] 3 2 5 4 1
  ```
- R-4.0.2-64bit (win10)

  ```r
  set.seed(123) ; sample(5)
  # [1] 3 2 5 4 1
  ```

In R-3.6 and newer, you can return to the pre-3.6 sampling with:

```r
RNGkind(sample.kind = "Rounding")
# Warning in RNGkind(sample.kind = "Rounding") :
#   non-uniform 'Rounding' sampler used
set.seed(123) ; sample(5)
# [1] 2 4 5 3 1
```

Comment: The use of the function sample was part of the reproducible example and I have removed it for simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are not getting what you think you are.  Consider:

```
> unique(iris_big$Species)
[1] setosa     versicolor virginica 
Levels: setosa versicolor virginica
> sum(iris_big$Species == 'setosa')
[1] 83
> sum(iris_big$Species == 'versicolor')
[1] 80
```

What did you want to reduce to?

Comment: In this case, you're counting the same flower more than once, what I want to is to count how many unique flowers there are on each Specie.