# Same seed different results in docker R and local R

Tags: r, docker

I came across this problem when I was trying to reproduce my results in docker.

I set seed in both R and docker to be 2000, but the train/test split using the function createDataPartition are different in these two sites. Is it possible? How can I solve this situation?

Thank you!

---

Thank you for your comments! I checked that local R is 3.5.1, but the docker R is 4.0.2. It is the reason that causes the difference I think.

Now I have to change the R version back to 3.5.1. Is there a good way to change the version inside this docker image instead of rebuilding the docker image? Thanks!

---

In terms of storing random seed, I used RNGkind() to get my kind and normal.kind. I tried both:

```
set.seed(2000, kind = "Mersenne-Twister", normal.kind = "Inversion")
setRNG(kind="Mersenne-Twister", seed=2000, normal.kind="Inversion")
```

But the results did not change in docker.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is if one is R-3.5 or earlier and one is R-3.6 or more recent (see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62942195/3358272), then it's likely a *known change* in `sample.int`. However, since we see nothing of code or dockerfile, it's too easy to close this question as non-reproducible.

Comment: In order for `set.seed()` to provide the same splits across platforms, it is important that you have the same versions of R, RStudio and all package with which you are manipulating your data. 

You should be able to spell this out in your docker YAML, if you do not, you are likely pulling the most recent stables of each and depending on which functions/methods are used to sample data you might get different sets with the same seed.

Comment: @sconfluentus There is no way to guaranty that you get the same pseudo-random numbers from a PRNG on different platforms. If you want true reproducibility you need exactly the same system (including all software versions and even the hardware). The best solution for the issue at hand would be to store the pseudo-random numbers.

Comment: @Roland, that was my original understanding, which I lived by for years, but I was led to believe by R-Studio people recently  (not posters but devs) that in more recent versions that was not true. 

I think that the best reasoning for using containers is precisely to be 100% sure that results are reproducible. Thanks for the reassurance.

Comment: As for the issue with the version of R and the versions of all required/installed packages, this is a great use case for the `renv` package. Create a `renv.lock` file (which btw also captures the used R version) from your local machine, then install the packages from this lock file when building the Docker image (with something like `RUN R -e "renv::restore(prompt = FALSE)"`).